# Program to open .bin files that doesn't need installation

Tags: windows-7, images, portable, extract

I'd like to know if it's possible to open .bin files(image files) so I can extract its contents without having to install any software. I'd like some kind of software that is just download the files and run.

I'm running Windows 7.

Thanks

Comment: depends.  what platform are you using?  many linux distributions, for example, include software that does this out of the box.

Comment: I'm running Win7

Comment: so you're asking for software that doesn't require installation (portable software) that will "extract" the contents of image files.  (these aren't .bin/.cue audio images, are they?  those would probably need different software than standard ISO images.)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for ? http://www.pendriveapps.com/mobalivecd-portable-live-cd-emulator/

Comment: It doesn't need installation but it doesn't seem to support .bin files.

Comment: Yes, what you said. And yes, .bin/.cue files is what I have in mind.

Comment: Why can't you install it?

Answer (score 1):

All "installing" does is copy files (executables, resources, databases etc.) to their correct locations so that everything works as the developer expects.

A lot of software now just is "download and run" as it just expects all the files to be in the same directory as the executable. However, there is no guarantee that the software you have is designed that way.

Comment: So, the question remains, do you know some software that opens/extracts from .bin files that is just download and run without having to install it?

Comment: @devoured - I was just trying to say that it might not actually get you anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution which doesn't support bin files again but is native for windows os'es.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/mount-cd-dvd-disk-images-using-a-portable-app/

Answer (score 0):

[Alcohol 52% free edition](http://www.free-downloads.net/programs/Alcohol_52__Free_Edition) will mount the .bin files (assuming they are CD/DVD/Filesystem images) as a virtual CD/DVD drive, and you can install from that virtual CD/DVD drive. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'd have to install Alcohol 52%..

Comment: Why are you so against installation?